# Extrair ícone de um aplicativo

Tags: c#

Preciso pegar o ícone dos aplicatvos que esta aberta na tela.
Icones dos aplicativos, navegadores (exemplos pegar o icone do chrome , icone do word e assim por diante...)

Tentei fazer assim:

```
Process[] listProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process p in listProcesses)
        {
            Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(mo.MainModule.FileName);
            string uri = @"C:\imagens\" + p.ProcessName + ".ico";

            if (!File.Exists(uri))
            {

                FileStream stream = new FileStream(uri, FileMode.CreateNew);
                icon.Save(stream);

            }
```

Porem estou tendo o seguinte erro(Somente uma parte de um pedido ReadProcessMemory ou WriteProcessMemory foi concluída).

Alguém tem alguma ideia??

Comment: Que aplicação é essa? Explique melhor seu problema.

Comment: Rodei esse código aqui e os erros que obtive foram de acesso negado. Não obtive o erro que você descreve. Ao ignorar os erros (try-catch, com catch vazio), consegui obter todos os ícones possíveis das minhas aplicações.

Comment: Cara o meu não esta rolando e  continua com o erro que eu descrevi acima.

Comment: Está encerrando seu FileStream após de usar?

Comment: Abra o arquivo de [manifesto](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-manifest), [se não tiver gere um](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/manifest-generation-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017), e insira a linha <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" /> dentro do nó `trustInfo/security/requestedPrivileges`

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que eventualmente alguns processos não permitiram extrair o icone dos mesmos.

O que eu fiz foi adicionar um `try catch` para continuar a execução caso ocorra uma falha.

Lembrando que você terá que executar o aplicativo com permissões de administrador.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Elevate())
        {
            Process[] listProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in listProcesses)
            {
                try
                {
                    Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    string uri = @"C:\imagens\" + p.ProcessName + ".ico";

                    if (!File.Exists(uri))
                    {
                        FileStream stream = new FileStream(uri, FileMode.CreateNew);
                        icon.Save(stream);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName + " - " + ex.Message);
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execute o app com privilégios elevados");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static bool Elevate()
    {
        WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        WindowsPrincipal role = new WindowsPrincipal(user);

        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT || Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return role.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
}
```

Outro ponto que alterei foi o `Platform target` para `x64`